# Date after property not working fine in react JS using simple react validator package

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using simple react validator package to validate forms in react JS.
here is the link for package :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-validator
but for date type, after, before is not working fine although it shows an error message but for correct value it is also showing validation error message.

```
<input  type="date" className="form-control calender_icon" value={this.state.from} name="from" onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}  onBlur={() => this.dateValidator.showMessageFor('from')} />

{this.dateValidator.message('from', moment(this.state.from, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), [{after: moment().add(1, 'month')}] ) }
```

Change function:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I assume, based on the bit of code, is that it could be an issue with moment.

```
{this.dateValidator.message('from', moment(this.state.from, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), [{after: moment().add(1, 'month')}] ) }
```

try this

```
{this.dateValidator.message('from', moment(this.state.from, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), [{after: moment().add(1, 'month').format('YYYY/MM/DD')}] ) }
```